# Find - using PHP and wrap everything after in <span>

Tags: php

I am printing using PHP

```
<?php echo $article->link($article->title()); ?>
```

This string holds something like

```
"Team Member - Job Title"
```

What id like to do is wrap everything after the dash in a span so i can change its colour.

Any help would be greatfully appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php
list($a, $b) = explode(' - ', $article->title());
echo $article->link($a.' - <span>'.$b.'</span>');
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

preg_replace is probably the easiest way to do this:

```
preg_replace('/([^-]*\s*-\s*)(.*)/', '\\1<span class="whatever">\\2</span>', $article->link($article->title()) )
```

Answer (score 0):

Not elegant, but fast:

```
$str = 'Team Member - Job Title' . '</span>';
$str = strtr(
    $str,
    '-',
    '- <span>'
);
```